# Bug in the reputation points

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I have answered the question and I have been voted "2", but the reputation points has not been awarded.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711281/naming-convention-for-number-of/2711409#2711409

This is to bring to your notice, if any bug on this. Please check and clarify me about it

Comment: This needs to be on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also - read the FAQ on reputation and you'll see why you didn't get any for that question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a community wiki.

See also: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Answer (score 0):

It's community wiki. How can you get points for that?

Comment: <strike>-1</strike> flagged for tone; this implies that everyone knows the no-points-for-CW-rule, but the OP obviously doesn't, so it's just insulting.